# Sonarqube not detecting LCOV report generated using mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sonarqube

I have created a simple project using Node.js, mocha and generated the report for code coverage and unit testing as follows:

```
mocha -R lcov  --ui tdd    > coverage/coverage.lcov

mocha -R xunit  --ui tdd  > coverage/TEST-all.xml
```

The reports generated using the sonar runner does not reflect the coverage on Sonarqube. The sample test javascript project using LCOV that ships with the sonar-examples-master as well shows 0% code coverage in Sonarqube.

The sonar properties set are as follows:

```
sonar.language=js
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.tests=test
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=coverage
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/coverage.lcov
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
```

Looking forward for inputs on how to resolve this issue and enable the SonarQube to report the coverage on an existing LCOV report.

Thanks,

Neo

Answer (score 1):

JS Test Driver was removed as part of the Sonar Javascript 1.5 release, http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3408

So I switched back to the 1.4 plugin.

Regarding the LCOV, I had to match the paths in the LCOV with sonar.sources path.
So 
sonar.sources=webapp/app

LCOV was like
SF:webapp/app/path/to/js.js

Hope that helps, I can correct anything I might have gotten wrong tomorrow when I'm at work again.